# How to loop through an array indefinitely and display the value in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, while-loop, components

I have an array of words and my goal is to display each one of them in an HTML template every few seconds. The result should be something like this: https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/iPortfolio/

I know it is possible to do so by using the following JavaScript Code:

```
  const typed = select('.typed')
  if (typed) {
    let typed_strings = typed.getAttribute('data-typed-items')
    typed_strings = typed_strings.split(',')
    new Typed('.typed', {
      strings: typed_strings,
      loop: true,
      typeSpeed: 100,
      backSpeed: 50,
      backDelay: 2000
    });
  }
```

I tried to replicate the same effect using typescript and I wrote the following code instead:

```
export class HeroComponent implements OnInit {

  words: string[] = ['marco', 'polo'];
  word: string = "";
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
    while(true){
      for (let i=0; i < this.words.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(() => {
        this.word = this.words[i];
        console.log(this.word)
      }, 4000)
      };
    }}, 4000);
  }
}
```

However once I run the website it says that it runs out of memory.

Would you be able to suggest a smart and elegant way to achieve the effect linked in the website above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be the way to do it:

```js
import { map, timer } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class HeroComponent {
  words = ['marco', 'polo'];
  word = timer(0, 4000).pipe(
    map((num) => {
      const index = num % this.words.length;
      const word = this.words[index];
      console.log(word);
      return word;
    })
  );
}
```

Then use the async pipe in html:

```html
<p>{{ word | async }}</p>
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7xbuft?file=src/app/app.component.ts

---

`timer` from RxJS emits integers in increasing order (0, 1, 2, 3, ...) starting at the first parameter (0ms) and then once every interval given by the second parameter (4000ms).

`pipe` lets us perform a series of actions on any emitted value before returning.

`map` takes the emitted value and returns a different value, in this case we use the integer to calculate the index of the array, then return the word at that index.

The `async` pipe will subscribe to the observable and unsubscribe when the component is destroyed, stopping the execution. Unsubscribing is important to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: Nice use of remainder `%` operator

Comment: @Drenai thanks, aka the modulus operator, good for keeping integers in a certain range. For example 12 hour clock runs in mod 12.